# How to load all pages of crystal reports at once

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-viewer

I am using CrystalReportViewer in my aspx page.

It is working perfectly, but it load one page at once; when I switch pages within report it does postback to fetch next page data.

[image]

Every time when previous/next button is clicked, this loader is displayed.

[image]

Is it possible to load all page at initial state, so it won't need to postback and fetch data each time?

These are setting of my Crystalreportsviewer

```
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
CrystalReportViewer1.DisplayToolbar = true;
CrystalReportViewer1.HasToggleGroupTreeButton = false;
CrystalReportViewer1.HasToggleParameterPanelButton = false;
CrystalReportViewer1.HasPageNavigationButtons = true;
CrystalReportViewer1.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Web.ToolPanelViewType.None;
CrystalReportViewer1.HasGotoPageButton = true;
```

Comment: Use of 'Sessions' should solve your problem.

Add the reportdocument object into a session and then use it, it will avoid the postbacks.

Comment: also refer this link-http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/8029cc96-6ff3-2b10-47a2-b30ea790ea5b?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&40145059315922..Hope it will help you

Comment: thanks @SmitaAhinave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use following:

```
CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
CrystalReportViewer1.SeparatePages = false;
```

It will remove NEXT/PREVIOUS buttons, it will use a scroll, and it should fetch all pages once.

Comment: Thanks @khazratbek, but I have some reports with 30+ pages; it is not convenient; endusers to scroll that long.

Comment: @DCODE But that is what they would need to do anyway if they got the report as a PDF